# YouTube Gdata API retrieving favorites using $yt->newVideoQuery

Tags: php, youtube, gdata-api

Maybe that's a somewhat uncommon question but here we go. Here's the code

```
$userName=("Google");
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

$query = $yt->newVideoQuery();
$query->setAuthor($userName);
$query->setMaxResults(3);
$query->setStartIndex(2);
printVideoFeed($yt->getVideoFeed($query));
```

And it works fine. But my client want to include his favorites list also.

It should be ok to use the

```
printVideoFeed($yt->getUserFavorites($userName));
```

But by doing that i cant control the pagination.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use `$yt->getUserFavorites($userName);` to retrieve user's favorites?

Alternatively, you can control the pagination with JavaScript, count the number of dom elements then perform the logic

Comment: Yes, that was the solution addopted. I've use php+js to solve this question. thx.